# Javascript rotating incrementing counter starting at 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment

I have an array of image IDs.

```
var images = ['238239', '389943', '989238', ... ];
max = images.length;
```

Array index obviously starts at 0. The **array size can vary**.

For example. If there are 5 images in the array, the indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

I'm swapping the images with Jquery by incrementing the current index like so:

```
<script>

currindex = 0

// Previous image, onclick event swap
    $("previous").click(function(){
        currindex = (currindex+1) % max;   
        ...some more code to swap image...
    });


// Next image, onclick event swap
    $("next").click(function(){
    currindex = (currindex+max-1) % max;
    ...some more code to swap image...
}

</script>
```

This allows the images to rotate and begin again at index 0 when user clicks "Next" on last index nr. 4. The same applies to rotating with "Previous".

I want to display a counter of current position like so:

```
<div>Image 3 of 5</div>
```

How can I implement the counter which will always begin at 1 at index 0 and will rotate both ways?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense, specifically: _"always begin at 1 at index 0."_ Why not just add 1 to the index for displaying the "Image X of Y" text?

Comment: `$('#someID').text( currindex + 1 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function updateCounter(){
   document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Image "+(currindex+1)+" of "+max;
}
```

Add some element to your code with the id of "counter", and add the function `updateCounter()` to both the click events.